# Getting current item ID in SharePoint Infopath form

Tags: forms, sharepoint, infopath

Can we get the current item ID value while submitting the data in InfoPath form.

I need to use this and concatenate the ID with other field value. Tired "Max(@ID) + 1" function but it wouldn't solve the problem.

I know it can be done using calculated column or workflow.

It needs to be done using InfoPath form ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You already figured it out yourself. Im assuming you are trying to use the ID in naming it.

1. Create a blank field.
2. Then add that field to your submission naming concat.
3. Create a receive data connection (assuming you havent) to that library.
4. On the Submit rule add the query action to that library and a set field action to set that new blank field with max(ID) + 1. Make sure Submit action is last.

That should do it unless Im missing something as I have used this many times!